# How to add RSS feed from feedburner.com to Thunderbird

Tags: xml, rss, feed

I found out that Google has a [Security Blog](http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoogleOnlineSecurityBlog) and I would like to add the RSS Feed to the list of my favourite RSS feed on Thunderbird:

[image]

Unfortunately feedburner.com offers a strange list of RSS feed: My Yahoo, freedly, netvibes, SubToMe, RSSOwl, NewsFire, etc... None of those look like a raw XML feed to me.

[image]

I see someone already faced this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687042/getting-raw-xml-data-from-a-feedburner-rss-feed . The hack

`view-source:http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoogleOnlineSecurityBlog`

truly shows an XML page but I cannot paste it to Thunderbird.

Why an old and basic technology like the RSS feed have to become so complicated? And is there any solution to this problem?

Is feedburner.com actively denying users to extrapolate the raw XML feed for some purpose? I don't get it.

Comment: FYI: The [actual blog site](https://security.googleblog.com/) has a link to a feed: https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/atom.xml https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvtsD.png

Comment: That link actually bring to feedburner.com where I was Stuck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL you link to (`http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoogleOnlineSecurityBlog`) **is** RSS (well, it is Atom, which is nicer and Feed Readers cope just as well with).

That is why you see XML source code when you prefix it with `view-source:`.

It just has a [style sheet](https://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html) so that if you visit it with a web browser, the data is presented in a readable format instead of an XML tree.

Just enter that URL (without `view-source:`) into Thunderbird.